# Using a "not equal to" sign as an arrow in tikz-cd commutative diagram

Tags: tikz-cd

I have the following commutative diagram made using `tikz-cd`.[image]

Here is the code:

```tex
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}     
\usepackage{geometry}                       
\geometry{letterpaper}                          
\usepackage{graphicx}                   
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}


\def\Z{\mathbb{Z}}

\begin{document}

$$
 \begin{tikzcd}[]
1 \arrow{r} & A_3 \arrow[hookrightarrow]{r}\arrow[equal]{d} & S_3 \arrow{r}{\textrm{sign}} & \langle \pm 1 \rangle\arrow[equal]{d} \arrow{r} & 1\\
1 \arrow{r} &\Z/3\Z\arrow{r} & \Z/6\Z \arrow{r} & \Z/2\Z\arrow{r} & 1
\end{tikzcd}
$$

\end{document}
```

I want to show that S3 is not isomorphic to Z/6Z by a not equals sign or something of the sort. How would I do that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It will be really helpful if you put here the code that you already have. This way, others can take your code, and add whatever is needed to solve your problem, rather than answering with a partial example or recoding your diagram.

Comment: My bad. Thanks for letting me know; the code has been added.

Comment: Unrelated: You should use `\[ ... \]` instead of  `$$ ... $$`, cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to

Comment: @DG' Thank you for letting me know; I will employ that practice from now on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can overlay arbitrary symbols with the option `marking`. Here I used `/` as the symbol, but you might want to choose another one that is fitting your needs / aesthetic preferences better :

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}     
\usepackage{geometry}                       
\geometry{letterpaper}                          
\usepackage{graphicx}                   
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}


\def\Z{\mathbb{Z}}

\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{tikzcd}
    1 \arrow{r} & A_3 \arrow[hookrightarrow]{r}\arrow[equal, "/" marking]{d} & S_3 \arrow{r}{\textrm{sign}} & \langle \pm 1 \rangle\arrow[equal, "/" marking]{d} \arrow{r} & 1\\
    1 \arrow{r} &\Z/3\Z\arrow{r} & \Z/6\Z \arrow{r} & \Z/2\Z\arrow{r} & 1
  \end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems so simple; I hope a similar question wasn't asked before.

Comment: Oops! As you can tell, I'm new to this.

Comment: @user227788 - you're welcome :)